# CSS: Gap between images and descriptions

Tags: css

I've come across a CSS issue with one of my layouts where there is a whitespace gap underneath all of my images and I'm not sure what's causing it. Any ideas?

All help greatly appreciated!

The site URL is: http://autovero.wpmad.com/showroom/

Screenshot of the gap (highlighted in Red) below:

[image]

Comment: @Gilles-AntoineNys - Thanks for your comment. I know what padding is but there is no padding (or margin) on the images - you can see that in the element inspector.

Comment: with answer of @evans you can also add rules `float: left;` and `font-size: 0;`  to `vehicle-image` class.

Comment: You have line-height: 1.7em; in your body css, set that to 0 and move that line to vehicleinfo css class

Comment: @KadirBušatlić setting line-height to 0 is not a good idea, it will affect other text ... all need is to set `vertical-align: top;` to image

Comment: Yes, I understand that, it is up to him to find what to set when he knows what cause this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to your CSS. It remove your gap.image default behavior is `display:inline-block` that why you see bottom space in image

```
img {
   display: block;
}
```